# How to access ubuntu server on two diferent public ips

Tags: ubuntu, ip, route

I'm strugling with the current problem:

Background info:

Ubuntu 20.04 on dell R710 server
I have 2 diferent internet connections with 2 isp supplied routers.
I've connected eno2 to isp1 router and get the 192.168.2.100 ip via permanent dhcp lease.
I've connected eno3 to isp2 router and get the 192.168.88.254 ip via permanent dhcp lease.

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ee:7b:75 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ee:7b:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.2.102/24 brd 192.168.2.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno2
       valid_lft 41588sec preferred_lft 41588sec
    inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:feee:7b77/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ee:7b:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.88.254/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eno3
       valid_lft 486sec preferred_lft 486sec
    inet6 fe80::d6be:d9ff:feee:7b79/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eno4: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:be:d9:ee:7b:7b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...
```

netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno3
0.0.0.0         192.168.2.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eno2
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 docker0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno2
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eno3
```

The problem is I can only access the server on only 1 (random) public IP at a time if outside the lan.
If 77.xx.xx.158 (isp 2) can be accessed, 5.xx.xx.55 (isp 1) is inacessable and viceversa, random after each boot.

I need to be able to access the server on any of the public ips at any given time.

Thank you in advance for any posible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can make that work.

You'll run into issues with packets coming in on one interface and return packets wanting to leave on the other.
Actually that might be what you're seeing right now. When the first router responds to the DHCP request, you'll set up a default route going through that, and when the second router responds (and the ordering of their responses might give the randomness you see), you also set up a default route through that. I don't remember which of the routes linux will use in that case, but it doesn't really matter, so let's say the second route wins. (If it's the other way round, just switch first/second in the following.) In that case you'll get traffic coming in through router 1, being forwarded to your server, and replies being sent back through router 2. That will likely check it's connection table, conclude that there's no connection (being established) to the destination of that traffic (it came in through the other router, so that's the one who knows that), and drop the packet.
If you manage to convince both routers not to perform such a check, it might fail on another check or on a router at (one of) the ISP(s).